# navigationController?.navigationBar.isUserInteractionEnabled not working as expected

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, viewdidappear, isuserinteractionenabled

For the following viewController hierarchy, `isUserInteractionEnabled` doesn't appear to be working as expected.

NavigationController(ViewController A) --- pushes to ---> NavigationController(ViewController B)

In ViewController A's `viewDidAppear` method I set `navigationController?.navigationBar.isUserInteractionEnabled` to false and set it to true in ViewController B's `viewDidAppear` method. However, upon popping ViewController B and returning to ViewController A, the navigation bar remains enabled for user interaction. Any thoughts as why this may be happening are greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: by "pushing" you mean present modally? I think you can't "push" another navigation controller on an existing navigation controller, correct?

Comment: Or do you have one single navigation controller and A is root and you push B on it?

Comment: Did you set a break point inside A's `viewDidAppear` to see if it was executed?

Comment: try set it false inside `viewWillAppear` instead `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Upload code so we know what you doing

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be a bug for which you could get around by doing that on the main thread:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //...        
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}
```

But this still leaves a millisecond window where the `navigationBar`'s interaction is enabled.
You have to be really quick.

---

#### However...

I wouldn't recommend what you're doing; i.e. disabling the `navigationBar`.
You could lose the `back` ability, if it had one, because you're just disabling the `navigationBar` entirely.

**Suggestion:**

Since every `viewController` in the navigation stack has it's own `navigationItem`, that contains it's own set of `barButtonItems`, I would recommend you keep references of the `UIBarButtonItem` and enable/disable them explicitly.

i.e.

```
@IBOutlet var myBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //...
    myBarButtonItem.isEnabled = false
}
```

Furthermore, the state of this `barButtonItem` is handled in this `viewController` itself and you need not do things like `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` elsewhere.